Unable to properly parse Project List JSON
I am trying to open Feast UI according to the tutorial (part Importing as a module to integrate with an existing React App) https://docs.feast.dev/reference/alpha-web-ui
My actions
npx create-react-app your-feast-ui
cd  your-feast-ui
yarn add @feast-dev/feast-ui
yarn add @elastic/eui @elastic/datemath @emotion/react moment prop-types inter-ui react-query react-router-dom use-query-params zod typescript query-string d3 @types/d3

Then modified index.js accroding to the tutorial
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";

import FeastUI from "@feast-dev/feast-ui";
import "@feast-dev/feast-ui/dist/feast-ui.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <FeastUI />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

Created file project-list.json in your-feast-ui/
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "Credit Score Project",
      "description": "Project for credit scoring team and associated models.",
      "id": "credit_score_project",
      "registryPath": "/registry.json"
    }
  ]
}

Finally started  yarn start
I have an error
Error

Error: Unable to properly parse Project List JSON. Check that your project list is formatted properly.
    at new ProjectListError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41857:24)
    at anticipatedProjectListErrors (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41870:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41891:30

How to fix it?
